# How to debug the error "No definition for method 'ios_base::ios_base"

Tags: c++

I am working on Catapul System level synthesis and trying to implement a code in C++ while during compiling I am getting an error:

> No definition for method 'ios_base::ios_base

Please help to remove this error.

```
#include<ac_int.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma hls_design top
int main() {

     ac_int<3>R;
     ac_int<3>G;
     ac_int<3>B;

      fstream rfile;
      rfile.open("image_r.txt",fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
         if (rfile.is_open())
           {

            rfile>>R>>G>>B;
           rfile.close();   
           }

    int fr = R / 255;
    int fg= G/ 255;
    int fb = B / 255;

  ac_int<3>Y = ac_int<3> ((0.2989 * fr )+ (0.5866 * fg) + (0.1145 * fb));
ac_int<3>Cb = ac_int<3> ((-0.1687 * fr) - (0.3313 * fg) + (0.5000 * fb));
ac_int<3>Cr = ac_int<3> ((0.5000 * fr )- (0.4184 * fg) - (0.0816 * fb));

 fstream wfile("image_w.txt",fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary); 
        if (wfile.is_open())
          {
               wfile<<Y<<Cb<<Cr<<endl;
               wfile.close();
         }


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Dont use `#include <iostream.h>` use `#include <iostream>`. Same for `fstream`.

Comment: Get rid of the .h on the standard headers.  `<iostream>` not `<iostream.h>`. Voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 0):

The headers iostream and fstream don't require an extension. In your code however you typed:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
```

So you should change it into:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
```

removing the .h extensions and probably also removing the errors generated by the compiler.

AND DON'T USE `using namespace std;`
Trust me as your project gets bigger and bigger this will make things more and more difficult. Instead add the namespace `std::` manually.